Research on Direct Preference Optimization in subsequence of the response
I wanted to start research on Direct Preference Optimization (DPO) but in the specific case where we're interested in part of the generated sentence, as if we could highlight where the model gave a bad response, and train specifically on it.
More rigorously, given a generated sequence of tokens $\{y_1, y_2, ..., y_t\}$, I wanted to fine-tune the model on a selected range $\{y_i, ..., y_{i+k}\}$.
Could I use DPO directly by doing $\pi_\theta(y_i, ..., y_{i+k}\vert x, y_1, ..., y_{i-1})$? Or could similar works be pointed out?
Thanks!
